# How to use Datepicker in django

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker

I want to implement a django form with datepicker. I made my **forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
```

and
**views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        f = DateRangeForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            c = f.save(commit = False)
            c.end_date = timezone.now()
            c.save()
    else:
        f = DateRangeForm()
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = f


    return render(request, 'trial_balance.html', {
        'form': f
    })
```

**balance.html**

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    Start Date:{{ form.start_date }}&nbsp;&nbsp; End Date:{{ form.end_date }}<br/>
    <input  type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "See Results">
    </form>

</div>
```

And still there is no datepicker in my input box of that form.
I also tried with including my files link in the script as in my balance.html

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

still the datepicker is not working. But when including jquery in my html file, it also makes not to work jquery-treetable which I have implemented in my html file.

How to make the datepicker work ?

Comment: Widget will only give you datepicker on admin form. If you wish to have datepicker on page you need to have javascript activating datepicker for that form.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `forms.DateInput()` widget, instead of `forms.TextInput()`:

```
from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
```

To make [JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) work, you have to initialise it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that was super easy.  You might want to include a link to the Datepicker css: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: I've been almost an hour looking for different solutions, this is by far the best+simple+easy one. Thanks @niekas!

Comment: The code of the jquery is within the field .js you must call in the html of the template? Which way you have to call it? (I am new in django and I don't understand very well...)

Comment: @niekas How about if I have a ModelForm? Does this change the situation for using this solution?

Comment: @tilaprimera No it doesn't. The only difference is where to specify widget. E.g. in ModelForm you have to use ```class Meta: widgets = {'my_date': DateInput(),}```.

Comment: @niekas could you give an example for DateTimePicker as well? I can't convert this to that. Thank you!

Comment: The popup just shows date, how I can have Date+Time simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

*The example below uses Django's generic.CreateView:*

**models.py file**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_due_date = models.DateField()
```

**views.py file**

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput

class add_task(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = '__all__'
    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['task_due_date'].widget = DatePickerInput()
        return form
    template_name = 'team/add_task.html'
```

**templates/add_task.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block body %}

{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{{ form.media }}

<h1>Add a Task</h1>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'team:add_task' %}" id="taskForm">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Add</button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

With the end result being:

[Show end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuNuk.png)