# How can I add in django a Calendar visual widget to select a date?

Tags: python, django, forms, calendar, widget

I am crrating a django application and I have the next question: How can I add, in a form in django, an icon or a widget that helps people to choose a date? I mean, I don't want people to enter a date manually. I want them to select a date by a click in a visual calendar. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about the jQuery date picker?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery/development-bundle/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}.js"></script>
```

[Another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700321/996114) provides some relevant code snippets for integrating Django + jQuery Datepicker.

Comment: And How can I do it from a form in django? I don't want to create a form from the html code...

Comment: That's why django has templates. The link in the answer provides a viable integration of django's Form class, template rendering and jQuery's date picker.