# Django datepicker not working?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, datepicker

I am trying to implement a datepicker in a user profile page, but it is not presenting the datepicker when I click on the textfield. Any thoughts?

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('birth_date', )
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install datapicker library and jquery-ui and in your template 
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $( "#id_birth_date" ).datepicker({
          yearRange: "-120:+0",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          beforeShow: function() {
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 9999);
        }, 0);
    }});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This answer along with this post solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700185/how-to-use-datepicker-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that django provide datepicker for DateField by default. The problem may be that when you add widget to add class form-control ,It resets all the default class that are applied by django . 
Try removing your class

Your problem may be solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356289/how-to-show-datepicker-calender-on-datefield) post

Comment: Do you mean remove attrs={'class': 'form-control'}? I tried that and it still didn't work.

Comment: @arcade16 are you sure that django provide a datepicker by default to its DateInput Field