# How can i add a date/calender widget to django forms?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I tried following these [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700185/how-to-use-datepicker-in-django/20700321#20700321) and [this](https://www.derricksherrill.com/django/django-datepicker-widget/) but it didn't work. the widget doesn't load in the form and the js files gives 404 error in the console while it's accessible from the link. I use crispy forms to render my form.

**forms.py**

```
       DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

    # patient Form
    class PatientForm(ModelForm):

        birth_date = forms.DateField(label='Birth Date',widget=DateInput())
        class Meta:
            model = Patient
            exclude = ['user',]
```

**The Template**

```
           <h2>Add Patient</h2>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'patients:patient_create' %}">

                {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Add Patients</button>
                <p></p>
            </form>
</div>
    {% endblock %}

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

**The links of js files + CSS**

```
<script src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”></script>
<script src=”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”></script>
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css”>
```

**The errors in the console**

```
Not Found: /patients/”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”
Not Found: /patients/”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”
[18/Jul/2019 15:29:09] "GET /patients/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 6742
[18/Jul/2019 15:29:09] "GET /patients/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 6760
Not Found: /patients/”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”
[18/Jul/2019 15:29:10] "GET /patients/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 6742
Not Found: /patients/”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js”
[18/Jul/2019 15:29:10] "GET /patients/%E2%80%9Dhttps://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js%E2%80%9D HTTP/1.1" 404 6760
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

in my code i have many jquery versions can that cause the problem.I want a widget that's more user friendly than jquery ui so is there any other method that i can use to add a widget with the same way of jquery ui ?

Answer (score 1):

in your forms.py:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
     input_type = 'date'

class PatientForm(ModelForm):


        class Meta:
            model = Patient
            exclude = ['user',]
            widgets = {
                'birth_date':DateInput,
               }
```

Try this

Comment: now i get this error
 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'

Comment: have you removed this line  `DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})`  if not try removing it

Comment: so how can i refer to `DateInput` in the class ?

Comment: @AMMARRADY I'm not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: `DateInput` is defined in the line you want me to delete.

Comment: yeah,but maybe that's what is causing error, try defining it the way I answered. Just copy paste my code instead of your,and tell me result

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the modern browsers won't show a select date without making the `type` to `date`

here's what solved it for me

```
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker','type': 'date'})
# patient Form
class PatientForm(ModelForm):

    birth_date = forms.DateField(label='Birth Date',widget=DateInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        exclude = ['user',]
```

Answer (score -1):

What You want to add is the type attribute inside the widget attributes dictionary. Like this:

```
widget = forms.DateInput(
   attrs: {
        'type': 'date',
        'placeholder': 'your-ph',
      })
```

Comment: this is the query not answer